# Lower VPR in SPD (Surge Protection Device) is more protective?

Tags: surge-protection

If you have a universal power supply that can accept 88v to 264v connected to expensive security system. Isn't it if you use a 120v SPD (Surge Protection Device) with VPR (Voltage Protection Rating) of 500v. It's more protective than using a 240v SPD with VPR of 1200?

VPR or Voltage Protection Rating is the voltage seen at the load for a test surge of 6000 volts, 3000 ampere at 8/20 microsecond.

Even though VPR is a manufacture test parameter. Note it's based on typical surge voltage and current. So in the event your equipment is hit with 6000 volts, 3000A at 8/20 microsecond pulse, the VPR value (minimum voltage) would appear in your equipment. So if your SPD has VPR of 500v versus SPD with VPR of 1200v The one with lower VPR rating is safer right?

Therefore for those countries using 240v like Europe. Do you use 120v SPD with combination of 240-120v step down transformer to avail of the lower SPD VPR?

Comment: How do you protect the transformer?

Comment: How do you mean.. the surges can just pass through the transformer into the SPD.